# What should i do with "TypeError: store.addListener is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, flux, reactjs-flux

I write a react program with flux architecture

but when I want to run it, this error occurred can you help me what should I do to solve this problem

[The error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTG5s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use it as your runtime type checker :)
At some line there should be a function, should be displayed in the error.

Answer (score 0):

in your Store.js you do

```
export default Store;
```

but should do

```
export default new Store();
```